# Possible issues after removing images of deleted products from media/catalog/product folder

Tags: magento2, product-images, optimization

From what I understood Magento2 deleting product behavior, associated images of the deleted product are not removing from `media/catalog/product` folder.

I need to manage around **11.000 new products** in the database 4 seasons/year... after almost 1 year in production, I found **4,5gb** of **unused images**.

I don't really understand possible issues after deleting this images since products are no more in the database. How should I manage such disk usage increase in a Magento2 way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not use product image for creditmemo email or similar thing, you can delete the unused images.

You can do a backup if you find some regression.